# Combine - error type mismatch when using flatMap

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I'm pretty new to Combine. I'm facing the problem with compilator complaining about error types mismatch in such a situation:

```
struct Service {
   func save(text: String) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> {
      Just(())
        .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
   }
}

let service = Service()
let saveTrigger = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

let cancellable = saveTrigger.map { "text to save"}
   .flatMap { service.save(text: $0) }
   .sink {
       print("Saved")
   }

saveTrigger.send(())
```

It fails to build with error:
`No exact matches in call to instance method 'flatMap'`

If I use `setFailureType` like this:

```
let cancellable = saveTrigger.map { "text to save"}
   .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
   .flatMap { service.save(text: $0) }
   .sink {
       print("Saved")
   }
```

I end up with different error:
`Referencing instance method 'sink(receiveValue:)' on 'Publisher' requires the types 'any Error' and 'Never' be equivalent`

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sink(receiveValue:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/sink(receivevalue:)), which you are trying to call, is only available when the publisher `Never` fails.

> Available when `Failure` is `Never`.

This is also hinted by the second error message you got.

However, since you flat mapped the publisher to the publisher that `save` returns, which *can* fail, the resulting publisher of the flat map can fail too.

This means that you need to use [`sink(receiveCompletion:receiveValue:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/sink(receivecompletion:receivevalue:)), which allows you to handle errors:

```
.sink { completion in
    if case let .failure(error) = completion {
        print("Error occurred: \(error)")
    }
} receiveValue: { _ in
    print("Saved")
}
```

Comment: Are these "overloads"? I think they are just distinct methods (different signatures).

Comment: @matt "Overloads" are *necessarily* "distinct methods", right? They are distinct methods with the same name. I'm curious as to what you think overloads are :)

Comment: These methods do _not_ have the "same name". One is `sink(receiveValue:)`, one is `sink(receiveCompletion:receiveValue:)`. They are just two different methods plain and simple. Overloads would be, e.g., two methods named `doThis(_:)` where _only the type of the passed argument_ allows the determination of which one to call.

Comment: @matt ah, I see what you mean now. That is indeed a better way of looking at this. I forgot about the parameter labels!